# Dynamic Radio Button disappears when linked back to page

Tags: coldfusion

I have radio buttons on one page that clear when linked back to the page. I want to make sure they remain checked. The problem here is that they are dynamic, which I am not used to. There is a loop that may loop up to 5 times.

This is what I have tried for it to be dynamic:

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add]") 
    AND session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add] EQ "Yes" >checked</cfif>

<cfif structKeyExists("session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add]") 
    AND session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add] EQ "Yes" >checked</cfif>
```

HTML

```
<label for="FLResident_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">
   Are you a Florida resident?
</label>
<cfoutput>
 <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="FLResident_#Add#" 
      id="FLResident_#Add#" 
      required="yes" 
      <cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add]") 
         AND session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add] EQ "Yes" >
       checked
     </cfif>/>
</cfoutput>
<label for="FLResident_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Yes</label>
<cfoutput>
   <input type="radio" value="No" name="FLResident_#Add#" 
       id="noFLResident_#Add#" 
       <cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add]") 
            AND session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add] EQ "No" >
           checked
       </cfif>/>
</cfoutput>
<label for="noFLResident_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">No</label>
```

Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you seeting your radio button values into session when the form is submitted? If not they would be available in the form scope.

Comment: like so .. <cfset session.checkout.info["FLResident_#Add#"]="">

Comment: and <cfset session.checkout.info["FLResident_#Add#"]=form["FLResident_#Add#"]>

Comment: even the radio buttons ?

Comment: it throws this error  Invalid CFML construct found on line 259 at column 152.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

FLResident_

Comment: An expression beginning with isDefined, on line 259, column 118.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    A cfif tag beginning on line 259, column 113.

Comment: That is a compilation error. Your quoting is off here: `"session.checkout.info["FLResident_" & Add]"`.  That said, `IsDefined` does not support using associative array notation. Either switch to dot notation OR use `structKeyExists` instead.

Comment: hmm weird same error with structKeyExists

Comment: No, it works but it sounds like your syntax is still off. Please [add what you tried to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32788017/edit).

Comment: oh I had just changed isdefined to structkeyexists

Comment: Sounds like a good time to hit the documentation.